# Running away from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

Have any of you ever tried to run from sharepoint? I've worked with sharepoint enough to know that it is not something that interests me. My interests are more along the lines of APIs / backend / distributed development. Have any of you found ways, as consultants, to move away from sharepoint and keep learning other things of interest? I'm currently in a position where sharepoint is in huge demand and I can't quite find a way to simply step aside from it. any suggestions ?

Comment: Maybe you should point out that you're working for a consulting firm (or so I infer from your comment on @zmt's answer- you might get more focused answers that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I infer correctly that you work for a consulting firm then find out what other kinds of things your firm works on.  Learn those technologies better that the people who currently work on them for your firm, involve yourself in those projects, even if just in a hallway conversation manner, and come up with better (faster, cheaper) solutions for the problems your firm is solving.

Your options are really seem to be 3-fold

1. convince your boss your talents
   would be better used elsewhere
2. convince your co-workers they want
   you on those other teams
3. convince your company's clients that
   they want you, specifically.

Answer (score 6):

Learn Java, or Ruby.

The Microsoft sales model of "attach" whereby they sell a solution comprised of multiple technologies and then sell the next solution on the basis of "well you have already invested in SharePoint so you already have the skills in place and the infrastructure for this new bit of technology we have" is here to stay... it's very successful.

SharePoint is cloud computing for business who have MS shops... you avoid it by not doing C#. If you're doing C# then given enough time, your apps will need to run in the corporate cloud and you should be looking after your career by embracing it.

Just my 2p. Sorry if it's not quite the answer you wanted.

Comment: It's googd advice, as for the looking after my career part, this is exacly why i wish to move away from sharepoint, I do not see the value of this platform yet. I do find it has great potential but do not find it mature enough, this is primarily why i wish to put my energies else where i.e. .Net 3.5

Comment: Funny, because I'm beginning to move away from SharePoint as a core focus because of it's maturity.

Comment: spoon16 : you find it to be a very mature platform ?

Answer (score 4):

I know exactly what you mean. I think you don't mind the idea behind a product like SharePoint, but really hate the way its been implemented and how problematic it is. I know its a nightmare to work with.

As a C# developer, I cringe when I hear the SharePoint word, SharePoint is Lord Voldemort. But unfortunately it comes with the job of being a senior C# / Microsoft developer.

I say unfortunately because its likely if you're working in a corporate structure sooner or later you will end up having SharePoint in your solution. Not because its good, but because as others have said - MS use SharePoint as a Trojan horse to get and keep business.

There might be some hope with the new version of SharePoint coming out (2010). Maybe this will finally include a better programming / implementation model.

Otherwise either work for smaller companies (usually less pay, but not always), or try to play down your skills as a MOSS developer if possible. Never actively market them unless your salary depends on it. Remove the skill from your skill matrix, and turn down jobs that completely focus on MOSS. Some MOSS integration here and there you can live with. An entire solution focused on MOSS will drive you insane.

If all else fails, learn other non Microsoft languages, and within a year or 2, SharePoint will be but a faded memory.

I know lots of developers who are thinking about quitting IT because of SharePoint. I would say don't let it be the end of your career.

And finally bitch and moan, and inform managers on a weekly / daily basis, as to why you are battling in SharePoint. Let them know, and constantly remind them how bad a technology it is.

Answer (score 2):

When life deals you lemons. Make Lemonade.

Seriously, if you are seeing SharePoint in such high demand, maybe working with the beast is the best idea. SharePoint is really just middle-ware. SharePoint can simply be a distribution point for your solutions (i.e., a user interface such as a web application can be hosted on SharePoint through a Web Content part). If you look at it, SharePoint may even prove useful as a document respository or small scale data store, in the form of lists.

Comment: I completely agree, the benefits for the enterprise can be quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should turn down SharePoint contracts and accept contracts that interest you.

Comment: not always possible when you are working for a consulting firm, it's a nice wish though

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the market you are in you can simply tell your boss at the consulting company you work for that your not interested in doing Sharepoint projects anymore and that you'll be forced to look elsewhere if they continue putting you on Sharepoint projects. That would work around West Michigan where the developer demand is high and the supply is sub-par.

Comment: *note to self: look at job listings in West Michigan.

Comment: Housing is probably pretty cheap as well.

Comment: This was going to become a possible next step in the next few weeks

Answer (score 0):

I'm, on the other hand, just starting to use SharePoint to enreach my currently boring C#-only projects. I'm starting to use it as a front-end to the distributed and complicated systems: simple configuration and customization, reporting, management, system control - looks like all this is available in this package it it's easy to make is usable by non-techies and by beginners.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't want to work with SharePoint anymore. I've worked on developing a solution for it and even went full charge with a web integration of it. I hated it.

First you have to master the awful programming model then handle all the deployments and it's not even the beginning. If you are developing a product for SharePoint, you have to debug the software itself which is a feat on it's own.

My solution to this is to be very upfront about it. I don't mind doing knowledge transfer and helping out people but I don't want to be developing/deploying SharePoint applications.

My boss get it, my friends get it.

Our latest joke come from someone who said a few months ago that it was "easy and fast to deploy application with SharePoint". The joke? "Did he just put easy/fast in the same sentence as SharePoint?"

So unless you salary would be lower because of it... downplay your skills on it and be upfront to your boss. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever looked at Alfresco (http://alfresco.com)?

It serves many of the same purposes as SharePoint, but does it from an Open Source J2EE application. It will leverage your existing collaboration / content management experience and expose you to a whole bunch of open source technologies.

Full disclosure: I work for Alfresco.

Comment: Alfresco could be an interesting alternative. I must admit that I'm a .Net consultant, and wish to keep pushing in that direction. My original post was not really about recommending something to a client. But more about taking my career into my own hands and giving it the direction which I was looking for.

Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a look at the website.

Answer (score 0):

I've already given this suggestion to another guy...Running from SharePoint won't be difficult because technologies are similar to each other according to their structure. SharePoint is not the worst technology to be used, although it is limited in some way... Fortunately, software sphere is too wide to be afraid of not finding anything you can be interested in.